# How to access variables from different classes?

Tags: c++, math, geometry

So I'm a begging in C++, Im making a program to calculate the area and the perimeter of a triangle when the user inputs the base, height and sides. I have 2 classes, Area and Perimeter, I need to access the variable "base" from Area and use them in Perimeter, since I need the base to calculate perimeter. How can I do this? Also would it be more effective to use one class for this program?

Area.h

```
#ifndef AREA_H
#define AREA_H
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


class Area
{
    private:
        int height;
    public:
        int base;
        Area();
        int calcArea();


};

#endif // AREA_H
```

Area.cpp

```
#include "Area.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

Area::Area()
{
    cin >> base;
    cin >> height;
};

int Area::calcArea(){
int answer;
answer = (base * height)/2;
return answer;

}
```

Perimeter.h

```
#ifndef PERIMETER_H
#define PERIMETER_H
#include "Area.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Perimeter
{
    private:
        int s1;
        int s2;
    public:
       Perimeter();
       int calcP();


};

#endif // PERIMETER_H
```

Perimeter.cpp

```
#include "Perimeter.h"
#include "Area.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
Perimeter::Perimeter()
{
    cin >> s1;
    cin >> s2;


}

int Perimeter:: calcP(){
    int answer;
    answer = s1 + s2 + base ;
    return answer; 


}
```

Comment: `Area` and `Perimeter` should not be classes. If you're trying to figure out the area/perimeter of a triangle, create a `Triangle` class that has `area` and `perimeter` member functions.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of creating two classes, Create a class Triangle.

```
    class Triangle
    {
        private:
           int base;
           int height;
        public:
          Triangle();
          int CalculatePerimeter();
          int CalculateArea();
     };
```

Define the functions.
Create objects of Triangle and call the functions.